# Customize form validation

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Am trying to customize a form validation via the controller for that.. I want to check if all mandatory fields (two text fields and one checkbox) are empty, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
$scope.update = function() {
  angular.forEach( ['lastName', 'umail'], function (input) {
         if ( !$scope[input] ) {
         alert( 'Input: ' + input.name );
         angular.element( $(input) ).css('border', '1px solid #ff0000 !important');

         return false;
     }
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="user_LastName" value="" 
    ng-model="lastName" ng-class="txtlnmcolor" 
    placeholder="{{user_LastName}}" class="input-lastname"
    required>

<input type="text" name="pemail" value="" 
    ng-model="umail" ng-class="mailerror" 
    placeholder="{{pemail}}" class="input-mail">

<input type="checkbox" name="user.TermsConditions" value="true" class="checkbox-terms" ng-model="terms" ng-required="{{checked}}">
...
...
<label class="btn-submit" ng-click="update();"></label>
```

Any Idea please? Thanks!

Comment: "it doesn't work as expected" --> How does it work then? Are you getting the alerts? Is it calling your `update()` function on button click or not? Specifics, please! :) EDIT: Also, you should probably not use jQuery to add the CSS to the inputs, but rather use either the ng-style or ng-class directives

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the alert.. but the border doesn't become red. I'll try with ng-style or ng-class. It's a good hint.

Comment: The ng-style is doing the stuff for text fields.. 

angular.forEach( ['lastName', 'umail', 'terms'], function (input) {
            if ( !$scope[input] ) {
                $scope.style ={
                    border:'1px solid #ff0000'
                };
            }
});

<input type="text" name="pemail" value="" 
    ng-model="umail" ng-class="mailerror" 
    placeholder="{{pemail}}" class="input-mail" ng-syle="style">

What about the  checkbox then regarding the lookup? It's not the value what it can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular native form properties like formName.elementName.$error or formName.$valid and the classes added by angular like .ng-invalid or .ng-valid . You shouldn't use dots on elements name, ie user.TermsConditions, it's easier to check if the element has got any error, you can use formName.userTermsConditions.$error instead of formName['user.TermsConditions'].$error .

For last to trigger angular native form validation use ng-submit and button instead of label

css code

```
.ng-invalid {
    'border', '1px solid #ff0000 !important'
}
```

html code

```
<form name="formName" ng-submit="update(formName);">

<input type="text" name="userLastName" value="" 
    ng-model="lastName" ng-class="txtlnmcolor" 
    placeholder="{{user_LastName}}" class="input-lastname"
    required>

<input type="text" name="pemail"
    ng-model="umail" ng-class="mailerror" 
    placeholder="{{pemail}}" class="input-mail">

<input type="checkbox" name="userTermsConditions" value="true" class="checkbox-terms" ng-model="terms" ng-required="checked">

<button class="btn-submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

controller code

```
$scope.submit(form) {
   if (form.$valid) {
       // YOUR CODE
   }
}
```

I hope this works. (sorry for my english)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'am forced to use the label and assign the event sumbit to it, cause am also using an Ajax call at some point - checking the email if it exists in the database or not and depending on the response I send the request with the rest of the data - after checking it - . 

So, First I've to check if the user did fill the mandatory fields and then I check the email. If I use the submit button, the Request is being send without stopping the process even if the Ajax response is: "false".

P.S. Your english is good.

Comment: in order to check if the email exists with ajax you can use $asyncValidators and the form waits until the promise is resolved to to trigger the submit handler.

Comment: I didn't know about this.. great!